# When a group algebra (semigroup algebra) is an Artinian algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

> When a group algebra (semigroup algebra) is an Artinian algebra?

We know that an Artinian algebra is an algebra that satisfies the descending chain condition on ideals. I think that a group algebra (semigroup algebra) is an Artinian algebra if the group algebra (semigroup algebra) satisfies the descending chain condition on ideals. Are there other equivalent conditions that determine when a group algebra (semigroup algebra) is an Artinian algebra? Thank you very much.

Comment: You mean the group algebra over a field?

Comment: DCC on *ideals* is a fine definition for Artinian commutative rings, but it is not so useful in noncommutative rings. An Artinian ring(/algebra) is usually one whose sets of left ideals and right ideals *both* satisfy the DCC. This happens, for example, for finite dimensional algebras over fields.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, thank you very much. Yes, I mean the group algebra over a field.

Comment: @rschwieb, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A result of E. Zelmanov (Zel'manov), Semigroup algebras with identities,
(Russian) Sib. Mat. Zh. 18, 787-798 (1977):

Assume that $kS$ is right artinian. Then $S$ is a finite semigroup. The converse holds if $S$ is monoid.

See this assertion in Jan Okniński, 
Semigroup algebras.Pure and Applied Mathematics, 138 (1990), p.172, Th.23.

Answer (score 6):

It is a result of [I.G. Connell, On the group ring, Canad. J. Math. 15 (1963), 650–685] that the group algebra $kG$ over a field $k$ of a group $G$ is left artinian iff the group $G$ is finite.

Comment: @LJR This paper (and the associated thesis) are a very nice guide for basic properties of group rings. I can also recommend Passman's book, for advanced stuff.

Comment: The same is true of Hopf algebras, by the way.

Comment: @rschwieb, thank you very much.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, thank you very much. Do you mean a Hopf algebra is left Artinian iff the Hopf algebra is finite dimensional?

Comment: @LJR, indeed. This was proved by Lie and Zhang in 2007 in Proc. AMS.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, thank you very much.